# Changing request.user in Django

Tags: django

I need to view site from admin as another user. Now I'm just changing request.user in middleware. Is it safe or maybe there is more correct solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Django packages has a list of apps that can handle user switching for you.](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/user-switching/)

Depending on your requirements, just changing it in middleware is a relatively straight forward approach that some packages like [django-masquerade](https://www.djangopackages.com/packages/p/django-masquerade/) takes.